# Watchman on my Mac is not working ? (React Native)

Tags: react-native

This is my first time using a Mac for react native dev so I installed
everything and made a project but when I try to run (npm run start) it gives
me an error. Thanks for the help if you can :)

jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.
Error: Watchman error: std::__1::system_error: open: /Users/struanmclean/Documents/Dovekie/App: Operation not permitted. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.
/Users/struanmclean/Documents/Dovekie/App/node_modules/metro-hermes-compiler/src/emhermesc.js:77
throw ex;
^

Error: std::__1::system_error: open: /Users/struanmclean/Documents/Dovekie/App: Operation not permitted
at BunserBuf. (/Users/struanmclean/Documents/Dovekie/App/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:95:23)
at BunserBuf.emit (node:events:527:28)
at BunserBuf.process (/Users/struanmclean/Documents/Dovekie/App/node_modules/bser/index.js:292:10)
at /Users/struanmclean/Documents/Dovekie/App/node_modules/bser/index.js:247:12
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
Emitted 'error' event on WatchmanWatcher instance at:
at Client. (/Users/struanmclean/Documents/Dovekie/App/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/watchers/WatchmanWatcher.js:150:10)
at Client.emit (node:events:527:28)
at BunserBuf. (/Users/struanmclean/Documents/Dovekie/App/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:107:12)
at BunserBuf.emit (node:events:527:28)
at /Users/struanmclean/Documents/Dovekie/App/node_modules/bser/index.js:249:12
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
watchmanResponse: {
error: 'std::__1::system_error: open: /Users/struanmclean/Documents/Dovekie/App: Operation not permitted',
version: '2022.06.13.00'
}
}